# What was Chandler Bing's job?

Tags: character, analysis, friends

In the series **Friends** everybody's jobs are well-known except Chandler's. He was very good in math and he did work with some kind of accounting or auditing job,  sometimes with the help of a computer or possibly some kind of computer software. Also, it was implied that he was very good at his job and he was paid with a good amount of salary.

What was his job?

Comment: He's a transpondster, I believe

Comment: @colmde THAT'S NOT EVEN A WORD!!!

Answer (score 70):

He worked in various positions throughout the series in a data processing company. He was initially a temp  in data processing for five years and later promoted to **data processing supervisor**. This is shown in S01 E15 *[The One with the Stoned Guy](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_The_Stoned_Guy)*

From [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandler_Bing#Career) of Chandler Bing,

> Chandler works as an **IT procurements manager with the specialization Statistical analysis and data reconfiguration**, which he takes up as temporary work and, despite working in the industry for years, thoroughly loathes. It is seen in many exterior shots that he works at the Solow Building.

In S08 E21 *[The One With the Cooking Class](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_The_Cooking_Class)*, He gets ready for a job interview. He mentions the name of his job.

> Joey: Sure, I can hang out ‘til I have to meet ya. (To Chandler) What uh—How come you’re not going?
>
> Chandler: I have a job interview I have to get ready for.
>
> Joey: I thought you already have a job.
>
> Chandler: And people say you don’t pay attention. No, this is a much better job. **It’s vice-president of a company that does data reconfiguration and statistical factoring for other companies**.

<sub>[Source](http://uncutfriendsepisodes.tripod.com/season8/821uncut.htm)</sub>

In S09 E10 *[The One with Christmas at Tulsa](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_Christmas_In_Tulsa)*, he quits the job.

> Monica: What're you doing here?
>
> Chandler: I wanted to be with you. I missed you so much.
>
> Joey: Hey, hey, uh, who did you miss the most?
>
> Chandler: Monica.
>
> Joey: Gotcha. (blinks an eye)
>
> Chandler: I never wanna leave you again!
>
> Monica: But I thought if you left, you get fired.
>
> Chandler: Turns out they can't fire me. **Because I quit**.
>
> Monica: What?

<sub>[Source](http://soncp.com/afs/910.html)</sub>

After quitting the job, Monica helps Chandler secure a job in advertising. Quoting from the same [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandler_Bing#Career)

> Monica helps Chandler secure a job in advertising through an old colleague friend of hers. Much to Chandler's dismay, he begins as an intern, which leaves him in the awkward position of working alongside people who are significantly younger than he is. However, his more mature approach eventually pays off, and he secures a full-time job in the business as a junior copywriter, even though he only expected to receive an assistant position.

So, he worked in a data processing company for a long time as a IT procurements manager and later he worked in an advertising company as a Junior Advertising copywriter.

Comment: Don't forget, he also cared a lot about his "[wenus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpUxn0tpLes)"...

Comment: I believe its shorten for Weekly Estimated Net Usage System. computer software they used in his company

Comment: Where does "IT procurements manager" come from? Wikipedia has no cites for it, and I don't remember it from any scene in the show. My memory is that he *does* "statistical analysis and data reconfiguration", rather than procure IT for it.

Comment: @AndyT I just quoted it but the Wikipedia doesn't have citations for that. Perhaps the Wikipedia meant Vice president of the company. They used IT procurement manager instead. Nice catch. :)

Comment: @KallumTanton -- have you checked out his annual network usage statistics?

Comment: @Vishwa If you are looking for this one, you can click on the tick mark.

Answer (score 19):

From this [video bit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86kPVkZUeTg) here, he explicitly mentions that his job involves doing **Statistical analysis and data reconfiguration for other companies**.

So, his job would basically come under the category of a data analyst or a business analyst.

Comment: yes, under the category of those. but I'd like to know his job. not category of his job. anyway thanks @Dawny33.